# Selector name for NSArray literal constructor, like @[]?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsarray, objective-c-literals

It's been a while since Clang added Objective-C literal syntax for `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, `NSNumber`, and `BOOL` literals, like `@[object1, object2,]` or `@{key : value}`

I'm looking for the selector name associated with the array literal, `@[]`.

I tried to find out using the following code for `NSArray`, but I didn't see a selector that seemed right.

```
 unsigned int methodCount = 0;
 Method * methods = class_copyMethodList([NSArray class], &methodCount);

 NSMutableArray * nameOfSelector = [NSMutableArray new];
 for (int i = 0 ; i < methodCount; i++) {
    [nameOfSelector addObject:NSStringFromSelector(method_getName(methods[i]))];
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@[]` is not a method on NSArray, so you're not going to find it there.

The compiler just translates `@[]` into a call to `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:]`. As in it basically finds all the `@[]` and replaces it with `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:]` (carrying across the arguments of course)

See the [Literals section here](http://nshipster.com/at-compiler-directives/)

Comment: Actually, I suspect that some "internal" interface to NSArray is used.

Comment: @HotLicks The [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) says that it expands to `+[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:]`, as Jonathan reports.

Comment: @Rob - But most of the array and dictionary constructors are not what they seem.  Different constructors would be used, eg, for an all-literal array vs one with dynamically created elements.

Comment: The key thing is it is syntactic sugar. That means it's a convenience form to type but gets converted to something else. The precise constructors or class cluster objects used are generally irrelevant and intended to be treated as irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

**`@[]` uses `+arrayWithObjects:count:`**

[Official Clang Documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

> Array literal expressions expand to calls to `+[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:]`, which validates that all objects are non-nil. The variadic form, `+[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]` uses nil as an argument list terminator, which can lead to malformed array objects.

When you write this:

```
NSArray *array = @[ first, second, third ];
```

It expands to this:

```
id objects[] = { first, second, third };
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:objects count:(sizeof(objects) / sizeof(id))];
```